# convert link list into python array

Tags: python, arrays

So I have a lot of links in this format:

```
www.web.com
www.web2.com
www.web3.com
....
```

and i want to turn them into a python array. So basically into:

```
"www.web.com", "www.web2.com", "www.web3.com", ....
```

Is there any way I can use search and replace or any simple program to make that happen? thank you.

Comment: You can read the file, split on newlines, and instantly have a list of URLs strings in Python.

Comment: Are the links in a file?

Answer (score 1):

just us `str.split` as follows:

```
links_str = """www.web.com
www.web2.com
www.web3.com
...."""
links_list = links_str.split('\n') # \n means line break
print(links_list)

# output: ["www.web.com", "www.web2.com", "www.web3.com", "...."]
```